# DirectX11 programs on directx10 gpu

Tags: c++, directx

So I have started learning directx11 using a book by Frank D.Luna. His examples are in directx11 and unfortunately on my macbook i have a directx10 gpu. Although I have modified a part of my code to include DirectX10 compatibility, I am using DirectX11 structs like `ID3D11Device`, instead of `ID3D10`.  Is this going to cause issues?

Edit:

I would like to point out that I am using Windows on bootcamp.

Comment: DirectX is an API for microsoft platforms. You can't use it on a Mac OS.

Comment: @JesseGood
I am using windows on bootcamp

Comment: Luna also has previous editions of that same book for DX9 and DX10. The DX9 one is quite good.

Comment: Yes I know. I wanted to learn directx11/10 because there are some significant changes, though I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't cause any issues. You can use the directx11 api and target the feature level you want when you create a device. When you create a device using [D3D11CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you specify a pointer to an array of `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL` to set the feature level (it attempts to create the feature levels in the order of the array). You can also get the feature level [programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you don't know it.

I would recommend reading [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Overview) as it explains all this stuff.

Comment: Yes I have done exactly that,well not me, the guy who wrote the tutorial :P. I just wanted to confirm before running into weird errors.